# Swift Doc-C - Selective data for documentation

Tags: swift, docc

Is it possible to select specific classes or structs for documentation ? As of now when I hosted my static website using doc-c command line it pulled up all the public methods for the sake of documentation.
Is it possible that I can select what folders within my code needs to be pulled up for documentation purpose ?
Any link , video, example  will be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably this helps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70085485/when-using-apple-docc-how-to-not-generate-documentation-how-to-link-to-uikit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocC will use `symbol graph` data from compilers like `swiftc` and `clang`.

By default, compiler will generate it from all *public* symbols. And we can config it to *internal* when generating documentation for an app.

TL,DR:

If you do not want your public symbol to be documented. You can use `@_documentation(visibility: private)`

For the full context, you can check the following forums posts and Swift documentation for Underscored Attributes.

https://forums.swift.org/t/nodoc-attribute-for-hiding-symbols-from-the-symbol-graph/59227

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/ReferenceGuides/UnderscoredAttributes.md#_documentationvisibility-